# Can nested objects each call getline from a serial file?

Tags: c++, file, oop, object

Suppose I have the following class hierarchy:

```
class Network 
    class Layer
        class Filter {
            class Neuron {};
            Neuron** filter;
        }
        Filter** layer;
    }
    Layer* network;
}
```

I devised the following serialization to be as human-readable as it is computer-readable:

```
Network=[layerCount]
    Layer=[xSize]
        Col=[neuronCount]
            Neuron=[xInputCount]
                bias=[value]
                Col=[weightCount]
                    weight=[value]
```

Ideally, one imports this file, and passes it to the network constructor. I am wondering if the network can then pass it, sequentially, to each layer, which can pass it to each filter, which can pass it to each of its subsequent objects, and so on. If using getline(), would each object receive its "nest" of lines, or would each start from the beginning?

```
Network(ifstream importFile)
    // read [layerCount]
    layer = new layer[layerCount];
    for (int layer = 0; layer < layerCount; layer++)
        Layer[layer].import(importFile);
```

More importantly, would C++ consider this legal?

Comment: As long as you're passing the `ifstream` by reference, there's no reason you shouldn't be able to do this.

Comment: Each call to `getline()` reads one line from the file. The End. Whether multiple calls to `getline()` occur sequentially in one function, or by a nested sequence of function calls is immaterial. Each call to `getline()` sitll reads one line from the file.

Comment: Thank you. Would you mind posting this as an answer?